# Is running chkdsk enough to make sure data is not corrupted?

Tags: external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I have a Seagate 500GB USB HDD...I was downloading a file with google chrome into the drive and then suddenly my system crashed...I restarted the system and ran the following tests on the disk:

(1) chkdsk G: /r

(2) Seatools Short Drive Self Test.

(3) Seatools Short Generic test.

---

(1) Detected no bad sectors, it says this line at the end of the operation: Windows has scanned the file
system and found no problems. No further action is required. here is the full report:
https://pastebin.com/tqDLtWw5

(2) and (3) also detected no errors and passed.

Is there still a chance my data is corrupted ?

Comment: I read the title, then the answer that starts with "yes" but in the context of the title it means "no". Please consider changing the tile so it's not the opposite of the explicit question at the end of the question body.

Answer (score 1):

The CHKDSK test tells you that, as of the time you ran it, your hard drive is OK (or not, if that is the case).

Further then, since you had a good test, it is fine to keep using it.

However, in the crash, the operating system and/or browser may easily have hiccuped and therefore there is no guarantee that data being downloaded and/or saved was not corrupted.

If the Save was complete before the crash, it should be fine, but I do not know how you would know that.

File that were closed (not in use) should be fine.

I would download the file again and (if you can) compare with the prior download (WinMerge can do that) or simply use the new file. I do this whenever I have a question about a download (not necessarily a crash).

Comment: I deleted the incomplete file that was being downloaded and then downloaded it again...My concern is other data on the disk (everything on the disk other than the file that was being downloaded)...is there a chance they could get corrupted ?

Comment: If the files were closed at the time of the crash, they will be fine. Only open files could possibly be problematic, but your posts suggests just the one file.

Comment: everything was closed except the files that were being downloaded which were replaced ...

Comment: So you are fine and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a chance that your data is corrupted, but it is small. Chkdsk checks the filesystem (is file names, indexes, file tree) and fixes it if need be. It does not check the contents of the files.

The Seagate tools do not know anything about the files or filesystem - they are looking at the disk level and are reporting everything is OK.

It is unlikely but conceivable that corrupt data was written to the disk within a file. The only way to know for sure would be to compare the files - although in practice, a compressed file would not likely not fully decompress if corrupted. While bit-flips and bit-rot do exist, they are not significant issues in reality.

Comment: I know that the files that I was downloading got corrupted when the crash happened...so I deleted the failed downloads and downloaded them again.. I am worried about other files on the disk which were closed and not accessed by any program when the crash happened..do those get corrupted as well  ?

Comment: Not due to a crash, no.